How to track API call in a specific angular components
I have a parent Angular component that contains multiple child components. I need to track all API calls made from the parent component as well as its child components, but I want to exclude API calls made from other parts of the application.
Requirements:

The tracking should include API calls triggered directly or indirectly by the parent or any of its child components.
API calls from the rest of the application should not be tracked.
The solution should ideally be implemented in an Angular application using interceptors or another suitable approach.

What I’ve Tried:

I considered using an HttpInterceptor, but it tracks API calls globally, which includes calls from other components in the application.
I tried manually tracking the API calls by logging them within each component, but this approach is not scalable or efficient.


The easiest way is to provide decorated/delegated HttpClient service at parent level:
{
  provide: HttpClient,
  useFactory: x => new HttpClientDecorator(x),
}

There are alternative options but it depends on many things e.g. mark requests with headers/params to enable detection from global interceptor, create new module for a group of componets and provide interceptor for this module only, create specific service for a group of components that will make calls etc.
